# How to retrieve the context object in spring boot from AWS API Gateway custom authoriser?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am running a docker image of a spring boot application in AWS ECS. The API is exposed through AWS API Gateway using VPC Link.

I have a custom Authorizer.

The output of the Authorizer looks like:

```
{
"principalId": "",
"policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    }]
},
"context": {
    "someKey": "1,2,3"
}}
```

I want to access the context object in spring boot controller endpoint. How to access it?

In Lambda, I can access it using the event object. But, I don't know how to retrieve here.

Value for "mapped from" as "event.requestContext.authorizer.context.someKey" in path/query parameters in API Gateway works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Integration Request" part of particular API in the API Gateway, we have to do a mapping.
I created a mapping in the "HTTP Headers" section in the "Integration Request".

```
Name: userId(You can have any name)
Mapped from: context.authorizer.someKey
```

context.authorizer.xxxx

xxxx - represents the key that you want to receive from the authorizer context object.

I received this value as a part of HttpServletRequest in the corresponding spring boot controller endpoint.

String user = httpServletRequest.getHeaders("userId");